# MATLAB - Wavelet coefficient based QRS complex classifier

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, bioinformatics, wavelet

I am new to Wavelet field and I wanted to ask you for a help for an idea.
I am supposed to create QRS complex (certain part of ECG signal wave)  wave morphology classifier based on Wavelets in other words, I am  supposed to create classifier which will separate waves with similar  wave shape to categories, like bins in statistics, but based on signal  wavelet coefficients.

I tried MATLAB mdwtdec and used wavelet coefficients on certain level as  an input for classifier which calculates distance from each QRS and  according to threshold separates to classes.

This approach is rather naive and I guess in order to improve it, I need some other idea or hint.

Comment: I don't understand why this approach is naive? Can you help me understand what would be an improvement? I don't get what the problem is with your method.

Comment: It does not produce good results.Below I found a better solution:

Comment: http://www.researchgate.net/publication/234834390_Robust_Classification_of_ECG_Beats_using_Discrete_Wavelet_Transform__Principal_Component_Analysis